# Account sobject, Name field, compoundFieldName property

Tags: fields, compound-fields

I'm new to SalesForce, and there's something I don't understand:

in the Account object, for the Name field, why is the compoundFieldName property defined to ... Name (the field is referring to itself isn't it?).

Why is it like this? What does it mean exactly?

[image: Account description in SalesForce workbench (partial)]

Comment: Have you compared that to any other fields?

Answer (score 2):

compoundFieldName indicates that the named field may be derived from a value set in this field. In this case, Person Accounts set the Salutation, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and Suffix to the Name field for Person Accounts, while normal Accounts use the Name field to specify the name. I realize that it's a pretty odd arrangement at first blush, but without this attribute, integrations which properly process the compoundFieldName attribute on fields would assume that Account.Name is not writable because of the presence of FirstName, LastName, etc. Obviously, this is not true, because it is writable, so this attribute prevents those integrations from working incorrectly.